# How to rewrite SQL queries who give better performance in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a project where all SQL queries was already written. Most of them can be improved, and I want to do that.

But how I can check and analyze the both queries [pre-written and I write same queries using different way].

I want to analyze the queries if I rewrite them then I can check if I did right or if old query is better than mine.

I need a queries analyzer tool for Mysql based RDBMS.

*[if any mistake goes then edit it]*

Comment: Any particular query in mind? It's an awfully broad subject to tackle.

Comment: I suggest using "EXPLAIN <query>" in mysql.  It won't tell how to optimize your query, but it will give you some helpful information about your query that you could use to "optimize your query".

Comment: See this for a basic tutorial to get you started: http://www.learn-mysql-tutorial.com/OptimizeQueries.cfm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has an `EXPLAIN` statement, which tells you what execution path the engine will follow. You can use that to determine what changes to make:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT foo,bar from glurch WHERE baz > 1 ORDER BY foo;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html

Pay special attention to the `rows` column, which shows how many table rows need to be examined to execute that part of the query, as well as the `Extra` column, which show more importantly, how the query gets executed.

For example, if you see "Using temporary" in the `Extra` column, that usually means that the DB will need to write the query results out to a temporary table (possibly on disk), sort them, and then re-read them (or at least *some* of them).

You can avoid temporary tables and other nasty performance killers by providing appropriate indexes. And not just *enough* indexes, but rather the *correct* indexes. Just because you've indexed a column doesn't mean that index can be used in your query.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a good RDMBS engine, the query parser should determine the most performant execution plan for your query, no matter how it is written.
I mean: the order of the tables in your from and join clauses, or the order of your filter-criteria should not matter.

The first thing to do, is look at the execution plan and analyze it.  Check wether you've to add indexes, or modify indexes for instance.

Your question is also a bit vague.  Can you give a sample of a query which you'd like to refactor ?

Comment: Emphasis on "should"; also, you need to structure the database well - the optimizer can try all it wants to optimize a table without any indexes, but the query will be slow anyway.

Comment: Many would claim that "good RDMBS engine" and "MySQL" are contradictory.  Certainly its query optimizer does not put the same amount of effort into optimizing complex queries as other databases.  (The flip side of that is that its optimizer is not as slow, which matters if you're preparing a lot of queries.)

Comment: @Piskvor: indeed, a performant database starts with a good DB design (as in, normalized)

Comment: @btilly: It's slooooowly getting better, but alas, in some unusual queries you still have to lead it to water and hope it will drink =/